# Graphing variables in real time for debugging in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, xna

I'm working on a project in C# using XNA. It would be useful to have a way to graph the value of certain variables in real time as the game is running. (Just for debugging, I don't want the graphs in the final project.)

This seems like something that has probably been done before, but I can't find anything other than this:

http://devmag.org.za/2011/02/09/using-graphs-to-debug-physics-ai-and-animation-effectively/

I'm willing to write my own system or use someone else's. If there is an existing released project, I'd like to find it so I don't have to reinvent the wheel. If not, what;s the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write the values you want to check in a csv file, then draw a graph with excel. [Here](http://knab.ws/blog/index.php?/archives/3-CSV-file-parser-and-writer-in-C-Part-1.html)'s a tutorial on writing a csv file writer/parser in C#.

The XNA hasn't support for drawing single line/pixels to screen directly (need to pass through a SpriteBatch). The only thing else I can imagine of is using a texture2D and draw your graph's pixels on it. You'll have to keep the texture in front of the camera though, with some strange matrix magics of which I don't actually know much. :P

Comment: Thanks. I'm really looking for a way to do this in real time. I want to be able to watch a variable while the game is running.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a pretty easy system using XNA.

You should have something very basic for plotting lines:

```
public void DrawLine(Point first, Point second);
```

Run this system on every frame to collect the variable's value. Keep track of previous value.

Draw a line between previous value to current value.

If the sampling frequency is high enough, you can get a pretty decent looking graph like this.

Answer (score 0):

The Xen graphics API has this feature. It appears to be for some built in variables, such as FPS, but it's all open source so I suspect it will be easy to add graphs of your own: http://xen.codeplex.com/

EDIT

I just remembered that Farseer physics also has code to do this http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/. It's probably easier to rip out than the Xen graphs.